# Terraform common variable usage in modules

Tags: terraform

I am writing terraform script to create ASG on AWS. I tried to create it with terraform `module` to have a more reusable code. The problem is when I want to use variable from `common-variable.tfvars` on the module tf files, it keeps saying it is undefined and need to be declared. This way, the module will be less reuseable  .

Here is an example

```
root
|
|___project 1
|     |_____ main.tf
|     |_____ common-variable.tfvars
|
|___ modules
      |
      |_____ a-module
                 |______ main.tf
```

So inside project 1 common-variable.tfvars, basically it looks like this

```
variable "a" { 
    description = "a variable"
    default = "a" 
}

variable "b" { 
    description = "a variable"
    default = "b" 
}
```

Inside a-module / main.tf looks like this

```
variable "name" {}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg-1" {
    name = "${var.a}"
    ...
}
```

When I do terraform init, it says

```
resource 'aws_autoscaling_group.asg-1' config: unknown variable 
referenced: 'a'. define it with 'variable' blocks
```

Any idea how i can use this common variable from within the module main .tf?

---

Update

I managed to pass `terraform init` by redeclaring the variable in each module. However, when i run `terraform plan`, this kind of error appears `invalid value "common-variable.tfvars" for flag -var-file: multiple map declarations not supported for variables`

Answer (score 1):

Wrong tfvars format, should be key / value only, such as:

```
a = "a"
b = "b"
```

Second, check how do you refer the module, should be something like this:

```
source = "../modules/a-module"
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. But the `variable a` actually contains more than just the value, as edited above. some of the variable is also a map, which i think i need to specify `type = "map"`?

Comment: for map, you can define it in tfvars file as `map = { us-east-1 = "image-1234", us-west-2 = "image-4567"}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variables required by the module within the module, and then pass them in when instantiating the module from your project.

Example stolen from [hashicorp documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html)

**In your project:**

```
module "assets_bucket" {
  source = "./publish_bucket"
  name   = "assets"
}

module "media_bucket" {
  source = "./publish_bucket"
  name   = "media"
}
```

**In your module**:

```
# publish_bucket/bucket-and-cloudfront.tf

variable "name" {} # this is the input parameter of the module

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "the_bucket" {
  # ...
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "deploy_user" {
  # ...
}
```